# Filter rows based on presence of a string element from another column

Tags: r, string, stringr, fuzzyjoin

I am trying to filter out relevant rowas based on the presence or existence of a string or part/element of a string in R. Following is the example:

```
colA                                      colb                           flag
New York Metropolitan Area                New York                       Yes 
New York Metropolitan Area                York                           Yes
New York Metropolitan Area                New York Area                  Yes
New York Metropolitan Area                Los Angeles                    No
```

Things I have tried till now:

1. Where 2 different dataframes are present

```
df1<- df1 %>% fuzzy_inner_join(df2, by = c("colA" = "colB"), match_fun = str_detect)
```

This option fails due to paranthesis and other special characters, cleaning them all up also did not help.

2. I joined the 2 dataframes based on an upper level hierarchay to limit the rows and created a dataframe df

```
df[, "lookup"] <- gsub(" ", "|", df[,"colB"])

df[,"flag"] <- mapply(grepl, df[,"lookup"], df[,"colA"])
```

Results not satisfactory as only limted rows are filtered.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You write *"Where 2 different dataframes are present"* but there's only one df in the question. Can you make the question more clear?

Comment: Please consider only attempt 2 as the one I am looking out for. I just provided mutiple approaches that may be taken and attempt 1 just describes that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.
The anonymous lambda function `\(x, y)` was introduced in R 4.1.0, for older versions of R use `function(x, y)`.

```
pattern <- gsub(" ", "|", df1$colb)
i <- mapply(\(x, y)grepl(x, y), pattern, df1$colA)
df1$flag <- c("No", "Yes")[i + 1L]

df1
#                        colA          colb flag
#1 New York Metropolitan Area      New York  Yes
#2 New York Metropolitan Area          York  Yes
#3 New York Metropolitan Area New York Area  Yes
#4 New York Metropolitan Area   Los Angeles   No
```

To remove the rows not matching the patterns:

```
df1[i, ]
#                        colA          colb flag
#1 New York Metropolitan Area      New York  Yes
#2 New York Metropolitan Area          York  Yes
#3 New York Metropolitan Area New York Area  Yes
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <-
structure(list(colA = c("New York Metropolitan Area", 
"New York Metropolitan Area", "New York Metropolitan Area", 
"New York Metropolitan Area"), colb = c("New York", "York", 
"New York Area", "Los Angeles"), flag = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Getting this error ```Error: unexpected input in "i <- mapply(\"``` when I run  ```i <- mapply(\(x, y)grepl(x, y), pattern, df1$colA)```

Comment: fixed and working. Thanks. Updated R. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you're trying to match partial strings and get a new column indicating the match:

```
df1 <- data.frame(colA = rep("New York Metropolitan Area ", 4),
                  colb = c("New York", "York", "New York Area", "Los Angeles") )
```

My first attempt was a simple `str_detect` but this tries to match the whole string in `colb` in `colA`:

```
df3 = df1%>%
  mutate(flag =  str_detect(colA, colb))

> df3
                         colA          colb  flag
1 New York Metropolitan Area       New York  TRUE
2 New York Metropolitan Area           York  TRUE
3 New York Metropolitan Area  New York Area FALSE
4 New York Metropolitan Area    Los Angeles FALSE
```

This is not quite right; though in this example you could just add `df1$colb =  gsub("Area", "", df1$colb )` first.

alternatively:

```
library(dplyr) # for pipe
library(stringr) # for str_detect
library(tidyr) # for separate

#separate colb into 3 columns (called b1,b2 and b3) with separate words (can be increased if more words)
df1 = df1 %>% separate(col = colb, c("b1","b2","b3")) 

# detect contents of columns b1, b2 or b3 in colA and create new column with logical value
df2 = df1%>%
    mutate(flag = str_detect(colA, b1)| 
                  str_detect(colA, b2)|
                  str_detect(colA, b3))
```

This gives output

```
> df2
                         colA   b1      b2   b3 flag
1 New York Metropolitan Area   New    York <NA> TRUE
2 New York Metropolitan Area  York    <NA> <NA> TRUE
3 New York Metropolitan Area   New    York Area TRUE
4 New York Metropolitan Area   Los Angeles <NA>   NA
```